# Usage of ParentMap in Clang

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, libtooling

There seems to be no examples online, according to the documentation [Path](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ParentMap.html), ParentMap's constructor accepts "Stmt *ASTRoot", which may means that later the ParentMap instance will find parents under the AST subtree under "ASTRoot". But how to get the root node of a translation unit? I tried

```
virtual bool VisitTranslationUnitDecl(TranslationUnitDecl *decl) {
    //decl->dump();
    Stmt *stmt = decl->getBody();
    mParentMap = new ParentMap(stmt);
    return true;
}
```

The goal is to create a ParentMap around the root nood then use it in other Visit*** callbacks during the scan process. But decl->getBody() is null. decl->dump() will print everything, and even scan the AST for the second time decl->getBody() is still null.

How to get the root Stmt of an AST? What is the right/better way to use ParentMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ParentMap` is not really intended to be used on its own. You can use [ASTContext::getParents](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTContext.html#a32d11844fdb82310b9059784fd4ceb6b), which constructs and maintains `ParentMap`.